# Typescript / react: returned object in context reducer with invalid property not showing an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, eslint

I have an interface for the return object of a reducer.

`cartReducer.d.ts:`

```js
...

export interface ICartReducerState {
  cartItems: ICartItem[];
  discountTotal: number | null;
  defaultWallet?: ICardDetails;
  orderLocation: ICartOrderLocationDetails;
  customerVoucherList?: IVoucherDetails[];
  orderType: OrderTypeOptions;
}
```

Then I have a reducer that sets the return type to `ICartReducerState`.

`cardReducer.ts`

```js
import { ICartReducerState } from './cartReducer.d';
import { CartActionTypes, CartAction } from '../actions/cartActions.d';

export const cartReducer = (state: ICartReducerState, action: CartAction): ICartReducerState => {
  switch (action.type) {
    // ... more case statements
    case CartActionTypes.UPDATE_CART_LOCATION: {
      const newCartState = { 
        ...state, 
        orderLocation: action.payload, 
        invalidProprty: 'invalid' 
      }; 
      // No error thrown for invalidProperty

      return newCartState;
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

[image]

`invalidProperty` should be showing up as an error because it doesnt exist on the`ICartReducerState` interface. It is important that invalid properties get detected as errors because there have been instances of developers introducing erroneous object properties into the return object of the reducer that sneak by the linter

Strangely, if I assign a new variable to an object with an invalid property directly it throws the error:

[image]

`.eslintrc.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    browser: true,
    node: true,
    es6: true,
  },
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2020,
    sourceType: 'module',
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: false,
    },
  },
  ignorePatterns: ['node_modules/*', '.next/*', '.out/*', '!.prettierrc.js', 'src/lib/auto-generated/*'],
  overrides: [
    {
      files: ['*/**/*.ts', '*/**/*.tsx'],
      parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
      settings: { react: { version: 'detect' } },
      env: {
        browser: true,
        node: true,
        es6: true,
      },
      extends: [
        'eslint:recommended',
        'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
        'plugin:jsx-a11y/recommended',
        'plugin:react/recommended',
        'plugin:react-hooks/recommended',
      ],
      rules: {
        'no-console': 'warn',
        'no-loop-func': 'error',
        'no-useless-catch': 'warn',
        'jsx-a11y/alt-text': 'error',
        'jsx-a11y/aria-role': 'error',
        'jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid': 'error',
        'jsx-a11y/click-events-have-key-events': 'warn',
        'jsx-a11y/no-noninteractive-element-interactions': 'warn',
        'jsx-a11y/scope': 'error',
        'jsx-a11y/media-has-caption': 'off',
        'react-hooks/exhaustive-deps': 'off',
        'react/prop-types': 'off',
        'react/react-in-jsx-scope': 'off',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion': 'off',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars': ['error'],
        '@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type': [
          'warn',
          {
            allowExpressions: true,
            allowConciseArrowFunctionExpressionsStartingWithVoid: true,
          },
        ],
        '@typescript-eslint/no-useless-constructor': 'error',
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": false,
    "alwaysStrict": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2017",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "esnext",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "types": [
      "jest",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist",
    "build",
    "scripts",
    "acceptance-tests",
    "webpack",
    "src/setupTests.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx"
  ]
}
```

Comment: You need to annotate the type here `const newCartState: ICartReducerState = ...`

Comment: @elclanrs I'm a little confused why I need to annotate it because the expected return value of the reducer function is set to `ICartReducerState` therefore if `newCartState` has properties that aren't in the `ICartReducerState` it should throw an error on the return statement. What am I missing?

Comment: TypeScript is a structural type system, so your object structure is compatible with the type of `ICartReducerState` that's why it doesn't error.

Comment: I am struggling to understand how it is compatible given that it has properties that don't exist on the interface.

Comment: I recommend reading https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html

Comment: The switch statement is actually creating a union in the return type. You are basically telling typescript this function returns ICartReducerState, which if you remove the return type you'll see that it returns ICartReducerState | { ...object, invalidProperty: 'invalidProperty' }. There's no way that I know of currently to enforce an exhaustive check of a switch statements return values in relation to the functions return type. The default case is returning ICartReducerState and for typescript that's good enough. Like @elclanrs said, annotating your object will protect against erroneous props.